# Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: food (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM food order by id asc 1

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

am getting this error in the Logcat when I compiled the program.

according to the Logcat, these are the two places that causing the error

1

```
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("Restaurants_DB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    locations = loadLocationData();
    addListenerOnButton();
    initializeUI();
```

2

```
    HashMap<String, Location> locations = new HashMap<String, Location>();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM foods order by id asc", null);`
```

Here are the 2 java classes that I have created:-

This is **MenuFoodActivity.java** class

```
public class MenuFoodActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    pizza mApp;
    private HashMap<String, Location> locations;
    ListView listView ;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_foods);

        db=openOrCreateDatabase("Restaurants_DB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        locations = loadLocationData();
        addListenerOnButton();
        initializeUI();
    }
    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        final Context context = this;
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Foods);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvFoods);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Object o = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        String pen = o.toString();

                        mApp=((pizza) getApplicationContext());
                        mApp.setGlobalVarValue(pen);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have chosen the" + " " +  pen, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //showMessage("Text","text");
                    }
                }
        );

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddFoodActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
    }


    private String[] getMenuFoods() {
        String[] menuFoods = new String[locations.size()];
        menuFoods = locations.keySet().toArray(menuFoods);
        return menuFoods;
    }
    private void initializeUI() {
        String[] menuFoods = getMenuFoods();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menuFoods);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id){

    }
    private void displaySelectedMenuFoods(String menuFoods){

    }
    private HashMap<String, Location> loadLocationData() {
        HashMap<String, Location> locations = new HashMap<String, Location>();
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM foods order by id asc", null);
        while(c.moveToNext()) {
            locations.put("- " + c.getString(1).toString() + " : $" + c.getString(2).toString() + "", new Location(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)), c.getString(1).toString(), Double.parseDouble(c.getString(2))));
        }
        return locations;
    }

}
```

The **`AddDrinkActivity.java`** class

```
public class AddDrinkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText ed_id,ed_name,ed_price;
    Button btnAdd,btnDelete,btnUpdate,btnViewAll;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_drink);

        ed_id=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_Id);
        ed_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_Name);
        ed_price=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_Price);
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("Restaurants_DB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS food(id int, name text, price int);");
        addListenerOnButton();
    }


    public void showMessage(String title, String message){
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.show();

    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        final Context context = this;
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Add);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Delete);
        btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Update);
        btnViewAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_View);


        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO food VALUES('"+ed_id.getText()+"','"+ed_name.getText()+"','"+ed_price.getText()+"');");
                showMessage("Success", "Drink added");
            }

        });


        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                db.execSQL("UPDATE food SET name='"+ed_name.getText()+"', price='"+ed_price.getText()+"' WHERE id='"+ ed_id.getText()+"'");
                showMessage("Success","Drink Modified");
            }
        });



        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db.execSQL("DELETE FROM drinks WHERE id='"+ed_id.getText()+"'");
                showMessage("Success", "Drink Deleted");
            }

        });


        btnViewAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM food", null);
                if(cursor.getCount()==0){
                    showMessage("Error","No records founds");
                    return;
                }
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                    buffer.append("Id: "+cursor.getString(0)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Name: "+cursor.getString(1)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Price: "+cursor.getString(2)+"\n\n");
                }
                showMessage("Drink Details",buffer.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
04-26 14:48:55.336 21103-21103/com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto E/DATABASE OPERATIONS: Database created /Opened...
04-26 14:48:55.593 21103-21103/com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto E/DATABASE OPERATIONS: Database created /Opened...
04-26 14:48:55.753 21103-21121/com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
04-26 14:48:58.743 21103-21103/com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: food
04-26 14:48:58.746 21103-21103/com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto, PID: 21103
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto/com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto.MenuDrinksActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: food (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM food order by id asc
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: food (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM food order by id asc
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:901)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:512)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1401)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1340)
        at com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto.MenuDrinksActivity.loadLocationData(MenuDrinksActivity.java:79)
        at com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto.MenuDrinksActivity.onCreate(MenuDrinksActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7117)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7108)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1262)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:101) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: improved code formatting

Answer (score 0):

Activity `MenuDrinksActivity` is called before `AddDrinkActivity` so table isn't created at that moment. I would suggest initializing database in `Application` class. This class is called before any activity so database will be initialized and tables created before you start using them.

```
public class AndroidApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // initialize database here
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register `Application` class in manifest like this:

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="com.example.AndroidApplication">
    ...
</application>
```